# Write to S3 bucket from code running in docker on EC2

Tags: meteor, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

This Meteor server code gets called in various places, the code running on my local development server saves a file to the hard driver.
But now it is running on AWS EC2 Docker container, How do I go about writing the file to a S3 bucket? thx

```
'saveToFile': function (fileName, text) {
   if (env != 'development') return;
   const playPath = '/Users/localPath/' + fileName + '.html';
   fs.writeFile(playPath, text, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
     console.log(`Saved to ` + fileName);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the NodeJS SDK for AWS.

https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-node-js/

Direct example -

https://gist.github.com/homam/8646090